# Python lists and for in Statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def print_list(x):
    for a in x:
        print(x)

c = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
print(print_list(c))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

In my textbook, it says that the code should simply generate the list however, 
in my console the list repeats 5 times and I used my debugger to see why it does that but it still does not illustrate how the output is 5 lines of the list. 
Help?

Comment: typo, change `print(x)` to `print(a)`

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_list(x):
    for a in x:
        print(a) #print (a),not print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must print(a), not x to print each item of the list.

Comment: Simply a typo.. :) I hope it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_list(x):
    for a in x:
        print(a)
c = [1,2,4,5,6]
print_list(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you are calling `print_list` function. Inside the `print_list`, you are iterating `list c`, which contains 5 values and print c as its. So 5 times you print `list C`, and comeback `print` function `None` to print in the main. Instead of C print a, your problem will solve and it will print values in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_list(x):
    for a in x:
        print(a)#here you have to print a
c = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
print_list(c)
```